# Integrating an external build system with (GNU) make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How to integrate an external, black-box build system like `go build` into Make?

I don't think this question is specific to Go, but I will use it as an example. The go build system tracks the relation between inputs and outputs (= the dependencies) internally, and avoids rebuilding the output if no inputs have changed.

I have a Makefile which contains targets based on shell scripts and targets based on invoking `go build`, for example:

```
my-exe:
    go build <some-url>

intermediate: my-exe
    <expensive shell script>

test: intermediate test-data
    <some test>
```

**Requirements:**

Let the make goal be `test`.

1. When I touch the `test-data`, I don't want to run the `intermediate` target.
2. When I touch the go source code, I want to run all steps.

---

Options considered:

- It is possible to list the go source files as dependencies of `my-exe`. However, my go source folder contains files for multiple targets, and I would have to somehow list the right files/folders in my Makefile. I could also overshoot and list all go source files as dependencies in the Makefile.
- If I turn `my-exe` into a phony target, then requirement 2. is fulfilled but 1. is broken.

Comment: When integrating Make and GCC it is common to generate dependency files during compilation. These dependency files are included into the Makefile. I suspect you'd like something similar for go. If that exists that is.

Comment: @Andreas I couldn't find a dedicated switch in `go build`. Maybe it's possible to parse the output of `go build -n`, but I would say it's rather ugly :(

Comment: Yeah. Using hashes of built files instead of timestamps is a better approach used by many other build systems (SCons, Meson, Bazel). That way even if you force `go build` the exe gets the same hash and the build system does not rebuild artifacts depending on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaud's solution will work.  But as in my comment above, I think all you need to do is take advantage of the FORCE target trick described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html

Change your makefile to this:

```
FORCE:

my-exe: FORCE
        go build <some-url>

intermediate: my-exe
        <expensive shell script>

test: intermediate test-data
        <some test>
```

By adding a prerequisite that can never be satisfied to `my-exe` you will force it to always be built.  Assuming that the `go build ...` command doesn't actually update the `my-exe` target if nothing changed and does update it when something changed, this makefile will work the way you want.

Comment: This is the simplest of all. Simple and elegant. I personally stopped using the `FORCE` trick after I spent some time trying to understand why our Makefile was not working as expected, before I realized that the equivalent of the `FORCE` target was actually an existing file, created by accident.

Comment: Turns out, `go build` _does actually_ update the timestamp of the file ‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

If we turn the external build step into a phony target, it will always be built. However, any target which depends on a phony target is *also* always built. [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that file.

There are two ways to use this:

---

1. Make the external build step depend on a phony target:

```
.PHONY: always-rebuild

my-exe: always-rebuild
    go build -o my-exe <some-url> # creates my-exe

intermediate: my-exe
    <expensive shell script>

test: intermediate test-data
    <some test>
```

(GNU) make evaluates the timestamp of `my-exe` *after* the target `my-exe` has run. If the target did not change the timestamp, then the succeeding steps (intermediate, test) are not run.

---

2. Introduce a dummy target to remove the "phony" property:

```
.PHONY: external_my-exe
external_my-exe:
    go build -o my-exe <some-url> # creates my-exe

my-exe: external_my-exe
    # do nothing!
    true

intermediate: my-exe
    <expensive shell script>

test: intermediate test-data
    <some test>
```

- `external_my-exe` is always built (if it occurs in the dependency tree of the make goal).
- `my-exe` is always built because it depends on a phony target.
- `intermediate` depends on an actual file (`my-exe`), so it is only run if the file's timestamp changed.

Comment: PHONY targets are always considered out of date. That makes anything depending on a PHONY target also out of date.

Comment: @Andreas Ah right the name of the phony target isn't considered as a filename.

Comment: @Andreas is right. In your working example `dummy_my-exe` is not phony, so during the second phase of its work, when the time has come to decide if `intermediate` shall be remade or not, make compares the last modification times of  `dummy_my-exe` and `intermediate`. While if it was declared as phony make would conclude that `intermediate` must be remade, even if a file named `dummy_my-exe` existed and was older than `intermediate`.

Comment: But the drawback of your solution is that if `dummy_my-exe` exists it will always be considered as up-to-date because it has no prerequisites. And its recipe will not be executed at all. So, even if it is older than `build_my-exe` its timestamp will remain unchanged and `intermediate` will not be rebuild.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for your insight. I have removed the dummy file, it seems to work still :)

Comment: @dyp With your new `my-exe` recipe that does not do anything you will still not do what you want. If `my-exe` does not exist make will always build `intermediate`, while if `my-exe` exists, its timestamp will never change and `intermediate` will always be considered up-to-date and remade too.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet But `my-exe` depends on a phony target, which is always considered out-of-date...??

Comment: @dyp Yes, but the recipe does not do anything to a file named `my-exe`. By the way, the last part of my previous comment should be _if `my-exe` exists, its timestamp will never change and `intermediate` will always be considered up-to-date and never remade_

Comment: `my-exe` is built by the phony target and therefore updated IFF the go source code has changed. And my tests indicate that `intermediate` is in fact only rebuilt if the go source code has changed.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how the `true` recipe can build anything. The recipe is always run because the `external_my-exe` prerequisite is phony but as the `true` recipe does not change anything...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet It _really_ doesn't build anything. The phony target builds the file. That is basically a hack. The target `my-exe` is merely to "wash the phony off" of `external_my-exe`. Because any target that depends on a phony target is always rebuilt. So we introduce one indirection.

Comment: Oh! The `go` command builds `my-exe`, not `external_my-exe`? Sorry, I did not understand that. It is clear now (but you could maybe make it explicit in your answer to avoid confusion). And yes, what you do should work too, for the same reason: the expensive target depends on a non-phony target which recipe always runs but not always updates the target.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Sorry for the confusion :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's abstract all this a bit with 2 targets: `always` and `expensive`. We want to always build `always` because it is cheap and it relies on a external build system. But we want to build `expensive` only if building `always` changed something. The solution consists in declaring `always` as phony, such that it is always remade, but not declaring it as a prerequisite of `expensive`, else it will always be remade too. We thus need a third target, `relay` that is not phony, that is also cheap and that will really change only if `always` did something.

In the following the `GO` make variable is used to emulate the external build system. If it is set to a non-empty string `always` changes, else it stays the same.

```
expensive: relay
    @echo "$@"
    @touch "$@"

relay: always
    @echo "$@"
    @if ! [ -f "$@" ] || [ "$<" -nt "$@" ]; then touch "$@"; fi

.PHONY: always

always:
    @echo "$@"
    @if ! [ -f "$@" ] || [ -n "$(GO)" ]; then touch "$@"; fi
```

And that's it:

```
$ make
always
relay
expensive

$ make
always
relay

$ make GO=1
always
relay
expensive
```

Comment: Ouch, yes I forget to add the phony target as a dependency of `relay` when copying my test into my answer :)

Comment: But I think it's not necessary to use a relay _file_, instead we can use the output of `always`...

Comment: IMO it actually adds confusion to rename all the targets :).  To be clear, here `relay` stands in for the OP's `my-exe` and `expensive` stands in for `intermediate`, and `test` is not shown but would depend on `expensive`.  So, you certainly do need for `relay` to touch a file (which it will do in the OP's example because it runs `go`).

Comment: However, you don't need to touch any file in `always`.  That target is `.PHONY` so having it create a new file is superfluous.  Once you remove that, you will see that you've basically implemented the FORCE target method, just with a different name `always`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html

Comment: @MadScientist _"relay stands in for the OP's my-exe"_: no, at least not in my intention. It is `always` that stands for `my-exe`, reason why it is phony (we want to always build it and let the external build system decide what to do or not do) and also a real file because the external build system creates a file with that name. `relay`, as its name says, is just a non-phony relay between `always` and `expensive`. It is there to avoid the direct `expensive: always` dependency that we want to avoid.

Comment: Like I said, I think renaming the targets adds confusion :).  In that case I think your solution could be simpler.  Basically, you don't need a sentinel file at all here (whether you call it `always` or `relay`).